# jQuery param() for associative array with values assigned at runtime

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to serialize to URL string an associative array whose elements are defined at runtime in the form of `arr[key]=value`, where key and value are determined at runtime, but `arr` is predefined as a global before runtime. I can't get the `param()` function to work with this kind of array. Is there another function to use to serialize such arrays?

```
var arr=[];
arr["apple"]="poisoned";
arr["banana"]="digested";

var str=jQuery.param(arr);
$("#results").text(str);
​
```

Comment: look to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462087/passing-an-nested-arrays-to-asp-net-mvc-using-jquerys-ajax/3463129 # 3463129

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use object notation instead:

```
var arr={};
arr["apple"]="poisoned"; // or arr.apple
arr["banana"]="digested"; // or arr.banana
```

While objects and arrays operate in a similar same way in JS its still better to think of arrays as being numerically indexed arrays, as opposed to hashes.

Comment: hmm if it's an object rather than array - would there be any trouble with using `delete` and `pop()` and such to manipulate it?

Comment: `delete` will be fine. `pop` will not work unless you create your own method and augument the object... But if you need named keys why are you using `pop`/`push`? I think this has become a more specific question about what you are trying to do... would you care to elaborate on what you are trying to implement?