# Submit array param with jQuery ajax/load

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, load, paramarray

`public ActionResult DoSomething(string[] arr, bool someBool, int someInt) { }`

trying to call the above method from jQuery:

```
var test = [];
test.push('dog');
test.push('cat');

$container.load('MyController/DoSomething',
                { 'arr[]': test, 'someBool': true, 'someInt': 1 },
                function(response, status, xhr) {
                    // ...
                });
```

the array paramater is null, other params are fine. What am I doing wrong?

Chrome developer tools shows form data being submitted as

```
arr%5B%5D%5B%5D:dog
arr%5B%5D%5B%5D:cat
someBool:true
someInt:1
```

not sure whats going on there but doesn't look right to me

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you are using jquery 1.4 you might need to set the [`traditional`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) parameter to `true` in order to be compatible with the default model binder format in ASP.NET MVC:

```
var test = [];
test.push('dog');
test.push('cat');

$.ajax({
    url: 'MyController/DoSomething',
    type: 'GET',
    traditional: true,
    data: { arr: test, someBool: true, someInt: 1 },
    success: function(result) {
        $container.html(result);
    }
});
```

or if you prefer the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method:

```
var data = { arr: test, someBool: true, someInt: 1 };
$container.load('MyController/DoSomething', $.param(data, true), 
    function(response, status, xhr) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: yep that's it. I've actually come across this problem before but had forgotten until this answer jogged my memory.

Comment: Thanks for the example using 'load' instead of 'ajax'.

Comment: Same issue happens with Java Struts2 and this fix is also good for Struts2

Comment: Thanks especially for these three lines:

var test = [];
test.push('dog');
test.push('cat');

I don't know what I was doing wrong, but until I re-built my array using ".push", nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `[]`

```
{ 'arr': test, 'someBool': true, 'someInt': 1 },
```

Posted values (checking with Firebug).

```
arr[]       dog
arr[]       cat
someBool    true
someInt     1
```

- [Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7dVuu/)

Comment: removing the brackets doesn't make it work, I already tried without. Though note the jQuery documentation gives the example with brackets, so I presume thats the correct way: `$("#objectID").load("test.php", { 'choices[]': ["Jon", "Susan"] } );`

Answer (score 0):

can you see if this problem is similar to yours:

[Passing an nested arrays to asp.net mvc using jQuery's $.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462087/passing-an-nested-arrays-to-asp-net-mvc-using-jquerys-ajax/3463129#3463129)

Answer (score 0):

Even i was facing error, in passing array from HTML page to aspx page.

my requirement was to load the aspx page in a DIV tag of the html page. on the page load i need to pass these JS array values to aspx page load.

i used below method.

`$('#<divTagID>').load("Targetpage.aspx",{"Arr":JSArrValues});`

In aspx page load event i can access this values as:

`string results = Response["Arr[]"];`

Thanks to JQuery API documentation [enter link description here](http://api.jquery.com/load/) and stackoverflow