# How to send response ajax into variable javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the following ajax request

```
  <script>

$(document).ready(function(){

          $.ajax({
        url:'obtenerusuarios',
         dataType:'json',
        type:'get',
        cache:true,
        success:json
         });

         function json(data){
          console.log(data);
         }      

    });

</script>
```

This Ajax request return the list of users and I want to change the results of this response into javascript variable. I need to replace the `availableTags` array with the new data in response

```
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Submit array param with jQuery ajax/load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942408/submit-array-param-with-jquery-ajax-load)

Comment: Are you using a translator? (I just want to help you convey your question better)

Comment: @simon I assume he means request

Comment: is the question related to autocomplete through ajax ? Because even if you point new array to the same variable, autocomplete will be using the old array (which it was initialized with).

Comment: Yes , I am using a translator , I try to write better.

Comment: Check the manual: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp (click the "view source" button at the bottom). This example is for JSONP, but it should work for you if you change the `dataType` to `'json'`.

Comment: @jcsa Was you question answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided the return from that ajax request is an array, you can try this:

```
<script>
    var insertar = function(data){
        // Maybe clean 'data' here

        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: data
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'obtenerusuarios',
            dataType:'json',
            type:'get',
            cache:true,
            success:insertar
        });
    });
</script>
```

You might need to clean the "data" inside "insertar" to adjust to what you want.